# Onblur event binding

Tags: javascript, events

I'm in the process of learning Javascript and I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu. An example of my desired functionality can be seen on the google homepage in the top menu with the "more" and "settings" dropdown.  Specifially the click off the menu and the menu disappears.

Maybe `onblur()` isn't the correct function to call.  I don't know.
I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

<head> 
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> 
<title>Untitled 1</title> 

<style type="text/css"> 
a 
{ 
    color:blue; 
} 

.info ul.submenu 
{ 
    border: solid 1px #e0e0e0; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 2; 
    display: none; 
} 

.info ul.submenu li 
{ 
    display: block; 
    border-top: solid 1px #e0e0e0; 
    margin: 0px 10px 0 10px; 
} 

.info ul.submenu li a 
{ 
    display: block; 
    padding: 7px 0px 6px 0; 
    color: #1177ee; 
    cursor:pointer; 
} 

</style> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function menu(id) {    
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(id);    

    myLayer.onblur = function() {      
        myLayer.style.display = 'none';  
    };  

    if (myLayer.style.display == "none" || myLayer.style.display == "") {    
        myLayer.style.display = "block";    
    } else {    
        myLayer.style.display = "none";    
    }    
} 

</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<div class="info">    
     Some Text Boom A <a  onclick="menu('id1');">Link</a> | More text   
     <a onclick="menu('id2');">Another Link</a> | more text   
     <ul id="id1" class="submenu">    
       <li><a href="dfhdfh">A1</a></li>    
       <li><a href="aetjetjsd">A2 This is Long</a></li>    
       <li><a href="etetueb">A3</a></li>    
     </ul>    
    <ul id="id2" class="submenu">    
       <li><a href="dfhdfh">B1</a></li>    
       <li><a href="aetjetjsd">B2</a></li>    
       <li><a href="etetueb">B3</a></li>    
     </ul>    
  </div>   
</body> 
</html>
```

The onblur event just simply doesn't work.  I have no idea why.

(Yes I know I shouldn't be using a closure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not firing because the UL never receives focus. Just showing it does not give it focus.

Two ways to solve it:

1. Add `tabindex` to both `UL`s and call `myLayer.focus();` after you show it inside the `menu(..)` function. This is not really nice because you do not technically want to `focus` your drop down and there will be a side effect of a focus rectangle drawn around your `UL`.
2. Register an onclick handler on the document that will hide any visible menu.

Answer (score 0):

As described here:

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onblur.html

The onblur event only fires on the following elements:

> Button, Checkbox, FileUpload, Layer,
>   Password, Radio, Reset, Select,
>   Submit, Text, TextArea, Window.

It looks like you're trying to use that event on a UL element. Instead I'd recommend using a `onclick` event on `document` to hide the popup.